# Laravel 9 split records based on 1 parameter

Tags: laravel, crud, store, checkout

Controller creates records in 3 or 2 tables depending if the user is logged or not. Everything works fine, but I don't know how to upgrade it. My goal is to save "Order" into N rows with unique ID, splitted by 1 parameter (vendor). Then those IDs must be reflected in "order_id".

```
        // Store buyer's data if he is not registered
        if(Auth::check()){

        } else {
            $user = User::create([ 
                 ...
            ]);
        }
        // Store general information about the order
        if(Auth::check()){
            $order = Order::create([
                 ...
                "vendor" => $vendor,
                 ...     
            ]);
        } else {
            $order = Order::create([
                 ...
                "vendor" => $vendor,
                 ...  
        ]);
        }
        // Store product list assigned to the order
        $carts = Cart::content();
        foreach($carts as $cart){
            Detail::insert([
                "order_id" => $order->id,
            ]);
        }
```

Someone is making a purchase. Cart includes for example 5 products. Three items from one vendor, and 1 from another two sellers.

| Product | Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| A | Seller 1 |
| B | Seller 1 |
| C | Seller 1 |
| D | Seller 2 |
| E | Seller 3 |

What I want to achieve?

- 3 records in "Order" (individually for each vendor)
- 5 records in "Detail" (each product linked to order / vendor)

Comment: Seems like something is missing from your explanation that makes it hard to grasp what your actually problem is, as i read it wouldn't it be possible to loop the cart data to create multiple orders?

Comment: I need help with creating the loop that grabs cart data and split it by vendor name.